# How to create makefile target for obj files generated in temporary directory?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to learn using makefiles again. I have a directory structure like this:

```
build
  |- Makefile
  |- Project files, like visual studio project
tmp
  |- $(os name)_$(compiler)
    |- *.o and any other intermediate files
bin
  |- $(os name)_$(compiler)
    |- the compiled binary executable
    |- debug info, if any
src
  |- *.cpp, *.h
```

So I made this `Makefile` after a bit of googling and experimenting:

```mk
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall
LDFLAGS  := -lpthread
ASSUMED_OS := unknownOS
SRC_DIR := ../src

EXTENSION :=

# OS detection and extension assignment for windows redacted for brevity
# ... detect OS, set extension to .exe if windows

COMPILE_PATH := $(ASSUMED_OS)_gcc
TMP_DIR := ../tmp/$(COMPILE_PATH)

TARGET_DIR := ../bin/$(COMPILE_PATH)
TARGET := $(TARGET_DIR)/MyProject$(EXTENSION)

# $(wildcard *.cpp /xxx/xxx/*.cpp): get all .cpp files from the current directory and dir "/xxx/xxx/"
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
# $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS)): substitute all ".cpp" file name strings to ".o" file name strings
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(TARGET)

# Compile all obj files into an executable
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
# Compile all CPP files in separate obj files
%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) ../*.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

This works, but it creates the `.o` files next to the sources.

So I tried to change the `OBJS` variable and replace the path:

```mk
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
# Substitute src path for tmp directory path
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(TMP_DIR)/%,$(OBJS))
```

But then I get an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../tmp/linux_gcc/Job.o', needed by '../bin/linux_gcc/MyProject'.  Stop.
```

So I tried to create a different target, one that I thought would map the object file names that should be in `../tmp/linux_gcc` to the source names from `../src`:

```mk
# $(wildcard *.cpp /xxx/xxx/*.cpp): get all .cpp files from the current directory and dir "/xxx/xxx/"
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
# $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS)): substitute all ".cpp" file name strings to ".o" file name strings
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
# Substitute src path for tmp directory path
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(TMP_DIR)/%,$(OBJS))
all: $(TARGET)

# Compile all obj files into an executable
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
# Compile all CPP files in separate obj files
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

But when I do that, make always compiles the same `cpp` file for each `.o` file:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -c ../src/Job.cpp -o ../tmp/linux_gcc/Job.o
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -c ../src/Job.cpp -o ../tmp/linux_gcc/Worker.o
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -c ../src/Job.cpp -o ../tmp/linux_gcc/WorkManager.o
```

I think I am quite close, but how can I get this to work? I think that in the compile command `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@` I need something else than `$<` for the input file, but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

In your first makefile:

```
SRC_DIR := ../src
...
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
...
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
...
%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Yes, this *"creates the .o files next to the sources".* If you have a source `foo.cpp`, the variable `OBJS` will contain `../src/foo.o`, and the rule will build it.

In your second attempt you have changed the object, but you haven't changed the rule, so the only way Make knows to build `../tmp/linux_gcc/Job.o` is from `../tmp/linux_gcc/Job.cpp`, which doesn't exist.

On your third attempt you have the right idea, but there's a flaw in your rule:

```
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The variable `$(OBJS)` is a list of objects, `$(SRCS)` is a list of sources, so *each* object depends on *all* sources. And the automatic variable `$<` expands to the first item in the prerequisite list, which in this case is `../src/Job.cpp`, so no matter which object you choose, Make will try to build it by compiling that source.

This is a job for a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(OBJS): $(TMP_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```